# javascript why is this returning 7?

Tags: javascript

```js
var arr = [1,4,6,4,2];
console.log(arr[0])
for(var i =0;i<3;i++){
  arr[i] += arr[i+2];

}

console.log(arr[0])
```

I am new to javascript i dont get how the index 0 value is 7. Can anyone help me clear this?
Thank you for ur help.

Comment: `arr[0] === 1 && arr[2] === 6` and `+=` is the same as `arr[0] = arr[0] + arr[2]`

Comment: because that you have asked to print  `console.log(arr[0])` in for loop `arr[0] += arr[2]` which means `arr[0] = 1+6`

Comment: 6+1 = 7........

Answer (score 1):

in the first loop:

```
`arr[0] = 1` and `arr[0+2] = 6`
```

obviously

```
arr[0] = arr[0] + arr[2] is equal to 7
```

therefore:

```
arr[0] = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that:
In your loop, when `i` is equal to 0, `arr[i]` equals to `1` and `arr[i+2]` is equals to 6. 
Then, you're adding `6` to `arr[0]`, so `1 + 6` equals 7.

Pseudo code:

```
i = 0
arr[i] == arr[0] == 1
arr[i+2] == arr[2] == 6
arr[i] = arr[0] + arr[2] = 1 + 6 = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you changed the value at index 0 by executing this line

```
arr[i] += arr[i+2];
```

Answer (score 0):

During the first interaction of the for loop, i.e when `i =0`, the statement `arr[i] += arr[i+2]` becomes :
`arr[0]=arr[0]+arr[2]` =>
`arr[0]=1+6` ( as `arr[0]=1` and `arr[2]=6`) so now `arr[0]` it's 7

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 0th index and second index of array and that value stored in 0th index of array.
Code:

```
var arr = [1,4,6,4,2];
console.log(arr[0])
for(var i =0;i<3;i++){
arr[i] += arr[i+2];
console.log('Index:'+ i + ' Value:' + arr[i]);

}
console.log(arr[0]);
```

> Output:
>   1
>   Index:0 Value:7 ---------->  1 + 6
>   Index:1 Value:8 ---------->  4 + 4
>   Index:2 Value:8 ---------->  6 + 2
>   7

Answer (score 0):

Here let's see what's happening.

```
var arr = [1,4,6,4,2];
console.log(arr[0])

for(var i =0;i<3;i++){
  arr[i] += arr[i+2];
}
//arr[0]=arr[0]+arr[2]=>1+6=7 is stored in arr[0]
//arr[1]=arr[1]+arr[3]=>4+4=8 is stored in arr[1]
//arr[2]=arr[2]+arr[4]=>6+2=8 is stored in arr[2]

console.log(arr[0]);
```

So here you see each element of the array is incremented by adding its [+2] neighbour. So arr[0] is incremented by arr[2] that makes it 7.